# Tiny MCE - Restrict the options under "format"

Tags: jquery, styles, tinymce, wysiwyg, rte

The "Format" option in the toolbar contains the options like :

[image]

I want to know how to remove all / any of the options under this "format" dropdownlist.
Like I want to remove Bold, Italic , Underline.

Please suggest.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the Menu from within your init.  For example you might do this:

```
menu : {
    file   : {title : 'File'  , items : 'newdocument print'},
    edit   : {title : 'Edit'  , items : 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall'},
    insert : {title : 'Insert', items : 'link media | template hr'},
    view   : {title : 'View'  , items : 'visualaid'},
    format : {title : 'Format', items : 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat'},
    table  : {title : 'Table' , items : 'inserttable tableprops deletetable | cell row column'},
    tools  : {title : 'Tools' , items : 'code'},
},
menubar: 'file edit format table tags'
```

So if you remove the correct options from the 'items' list of the format menu they won't appear in the editor.

Comment: The defaults for the menus can be found in the theme.js file.  This will show you exactly what TinyMCE does for menus when you don't provide the menu and menubar options in your configuration.  Please keep in mind that many plugins also inject options into the menus.